# Is it necessary to close Android Studio emulator to update the app's changes?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Would like to know if it's necessary to close the emulador on Android Studio every time that I make changes on my app. If there's a way to "save" the changes e run the app without closing e open all over again.

Thanks!

Comment: No. You can just run the app from the IDE, telling the IDE to install the app on the already-running emulator.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Um, just run the app in the IDE. Android Studio will give you the option of running the app on the already-running emulator.